# Recursive method to print a descending then ascending integer sequence

Tags: java, recursion

From a programming assignment:

> Write a method `writeSequence` that accepts an integer `n` as a
>   parameter and prints a symmetric sequence of `n` numbers with
>   descending integers ending in 1 followed by ascending integers
>   beginning with 1, as in the table below:
>
> ```
> Call                        Output
>
> writeSequence(1);             1
> writeSequence(2);            1 1
> writeSequence(3);           2 1 2
> writeSequence(4);          2 1 1 2
> writeSequence(5);         3 2 1 2 3
> writeSequence(6);        3 2 1 1 2 3
> writeSequence(7);       4 3 2 1 2 3 4
> writeSequence(8);      4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4
> writeSequence(9);     5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5
> writeSequence(10);   5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5
> ```
>
> Notice that for odd numbers the sequence has a single 1 in the middle
>   while for even values it has two 1s in the middle.
>
> Your method should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if passed a
>   value less than 1. A client using this method would have to call
>   `println` to complete the line of output.

I wrote code that is pretty ugly, but produces the correct output. I've put this up to see if anyone had a more efficient recursive algorithm and to put the example up. There are not many hits about more complex recursive methods in Java when searching.

```java
public static void writeSequence(int n) {

    if( n < 1 )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    if( n == 1 ) {
        System.out.print("1");

    } else if( n == 2 ) {
        System.out.print("1 1");

    } else if( n % 2 == 0 ){
        System.out.print((n / 2) + " ");
        writeSequence(n - 2);
        System.out.print(" " + (n / 2));

    } else if( n % 2 == 1 ) {
        System.out.print(((n + 1) / 2) + " ");
        writeSequence((n - 2));
        System.out.print(" " + ((n + 1) / 2));
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can use a helper function, you could do this:

```
  public static void writeSequence(int n) {
    if (n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    writeSequenceHelper(n);
  }

  public static void writeSequenceHelper(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return;
    int m = (n+1) / 2;
    System.out.print(m + " ");
    writeSequenceHelper(n - 2);
    System.out.print(m + " ");
  }
```

If you can't use a helper function like this to workaround the strange IllegalArgumentException requirement, you could do this (which is similar to your solution, but a little more succinct):

```
  public static void writeSequence2(int n) {
    if (n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (n == 1) {
      System.out.print("1");
    } else if (n == 2) {
      System.out.print("1 1");
    } else {
      int m = (n+1) / 2;
      System.out.print(m + " ");
      writeSequence2(n - 2);
      System.out.print(" " + m);
    }
  }
```

Comment: public static void writeSequence2(int n) {
        if (n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (n == 1) {
          System.out.print("1");
         } else if (n == 2) {
           System.out.print("1 1");
        } else {
          System.out.print((n + 1) / 2 + " ");
          writeSequence2(n - 2);
          System.out.print(" " + (n + 1) / 2);
        }
      }

Comment: Not sure what your point is...

Comment: For some reason I cant figure out the elusive method of commenting in code formatting. Basically, I removed the local variable m and put the (m + 1) / 2 operation into the recursive call. After looking at your code, I realized that my n % 2 == 0 condition is unnecessary. Thanks for your help and perspective!

Comment: Don't think you can code format comments.  IMHO, the problem should only require an IllegalArgumentException when n < 0.  In-lining my local variable, m, is less efficient since it requires duplicate computation, but that's probably not significant if you like the way it looks better.  Please consider accepting my answer (by clicking the check mark).